# Prob. 6, Sec. 19, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Convergence of a sequence in the product implies the convergence of each coordinate sequence

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Here is Prob. 6, Sec. 19, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Let $\mathbf{x}_1$, $\mathbf{x}_2$, $\ldots$ be a sequence of the points of the product space $\prod X_\alpha$. Show that this sequence converges to the point $\mathbf{x}$ if and only if the sequence  $\pi_\alpha \left( \mathbf{x}_1 \right)$, $\pi_\alpha \left( \mathbf{x}_2 \right)$, $\ldots$ converges to $\pi_\alpha ( \mathbf{x} )$ for each $\alpha$. Is this fact true if we use the box topology instead of the product topology?

My Attempt:

> Suppose that the sequence  $\mathbf{x}_n$ converges to the point  $\mathbf{x}$ in the Cartesian product $\prod X_\alpha$, in either the product or the box topology. Let $X_\beta$ be an arbitrary one of the family of topological spaces $\left\{ \ X_\alpha \right\}$. We show that the sequence  $\pi_\beta \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right)$ converges to the point $\pi_\beta ( \mathbf{x} )$ in $X_\beta$. Let $U_\beta$ be any open set in $X_\beta$ such that $\pi_\beta (\mathbf{x}) \in U_\beta$. Then $ \pi_\beta^{-1} \left( U_\beta \right) $ is an open set in $\prod X_\alpha$, and $\mathbf{x} \in  \pi_\beta^{-1} \left( U_\beta \right)$. So there exists a natural number $N$ such that $\mathbf{x}_n \in \pi_\beta^{-1} \left( U_\beta \right)$ for all $n > N$, which implies that $\pi_\beta \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right) \in U_\beta$ for all $n > N$.
>
> Conversely, suppose that $\pi_\alpha \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right)$ converges to the point $\pi_\alpha( \mathbf{x} )$ in $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. Let $U \colon= \prod U_\alpha$ be a product topology  basis element containing $\mathbf{x}$. Then $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$, and $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many of the $\alpha$s. Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k$ be the indices for which $U_\alpha \neq X_\alpha$. For each $i = 1, \ldots, k$, as $\pi_{\alpha_i} \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right)$ converges to $\pi_{\alpha_i} ( \mathbf{x} )$ in $X_{\alpha_i}$ and as $U_{\alpha_i}$ is an open set in $X_{\alpha_i}$ such that $\pi_{\alpha_i} \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \in U_{\alpha_i}$, so there exists a natural number $N_i$ such that $\pi_{\alpha_i} \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right) \in U_{\alpha_i}$ for all $n > N_i$. Let $N \colon= \max \left\{ \ N_1, \ldots, N_k \ \right\}$. Then, for each $i = 1, \ldots, k$, we have $\pi_{\alpha_i} \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right) \in U_{\alpha_i}$ for all $n > N$, which implies that $\mathbf{x}_n \in U$ for all $n> N$. Hence $\mathbf{x}_n$ converges to $\mathbf{x}$ in the product space.
>
> How ever, the convergence of $\pi_\alpha \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right)$ to $\pi_\alpha ( \mathbf{x} )$ in each $X_\alpha$ does not necessarily imply the convergence of $\mathbf{x}_n$ to $\mathbf{x}$ if $\prod X_\alpha$ is given the box topology.
>
> Now let us consider the sequence the sequence $\mathbf{x}_n \colon= \left( \frac{1}{n } , \frac{ 1 }{ n }, \frac{ 1 }{ n }, \ldots \right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, we note that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to the point $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. However, $\mathbf{x}_n$ does not converge to the point $\mathbf{x} \colon= ( 0, 0, 0, \ldots )$ if $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is given the box topology, for the set
> $$ U \colon= \left( - \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right) \times \left( - \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9} \right) \times \left( - \frac{1}{ 16 }, \frac{1}{ 16  } \right) \times \cdots $$ is a box topology open set in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, and so if $\mathbf{x}_n$ belongs to $U$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for that $n$, we would also have $\pi_n \left( \mathbf{x}_n \right) \in \pi_n (U)$, that is,
> $$ \frac{1}{n} \in \left( \frac{1}{ (n+1)^2 }, \frac{1}{ (n+1)^2 } \right), $$
> which is not true.

Is there any problem --- either in logic or presentation --- in any part of the above proof?

Comment: I cannot find anything wrong in this.

Comment: Another simple example in the box-product topology on $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ is to let $x_{n,n}=1$ and $x_{n,m}=0$ when $n\ne m ,$ and let $V_n=(x_{n,m})_{m\in \omega}\in \Bbb R^{\omega}$. Then $(V_n)_{n\in \omega}$ converges co-ordinate-wise to $\bar 0=(0,0,0,...)$  but $\{V_n: n\in \omega\}$ is a closed discrete subspace that does not include the point $\bar 0$.

Comment: Your work looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite correct, but the squares are not needed: just use $(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ which (more) obviously does not contain $\frac{1}{n}$; why make it more complicated? Also the first paragraph can be summarised as "$\pi_\alpha$ is continuous so preserves convergence".